# access public method in extended class from protected method in extending class - javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance

i'm practicing with Javascript Inheritance, my first try is following code:

```
var base_class = function() 
{
    var _data = null;

    function _get() {
        return _data;
    }

    this.get = function() {
        return _get();
    }

    this.init = function(data) {
    _data = data;
    }       
}

var new_class = function() {

    base_class.call(this);

    var _data = 'test';

    function _getData() {
        return this.get();
    }

    this.getDataOther = function() {
        return _getData();
    }

    this.getData = function() {
        return this.get();
    }   

    this.init(_data);
}

new_class.prototype = base_class.prototype;

var instance = new new_class();

alert(instance.getData());
alert(instance.getDataOther());
```

to that point i am really happy with my solution, but there is one problem
that i dont get resolved.

the "getDataOther" method don`t return the stored data from the base class,
because i cannot access the public "get" class from the protected "_getData" method in the new_class.

How can i get that running ?

Thanks in advance.

Ps.: Please excuse my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment out the `this.init` function (which overwrites the `base_class` `_data` field) and make the `new_class`'s `getData` function just return `_data`, you should be able to get distinct variables.

```
var base_class = function() 
{
    var _data = null;

    function _get() {
        return _data;
    }

    this.get = function() {
        return _get();
    }

    this.init = function(data) {
        _data = data;
    }       
}

var new_class = function() {
    var self = this;    //Some browsers require a separate this reference for
                        //internal functions.
                        //http://book.mixu.net/ch4.html

    base_class.call(this);

    var _data = 'test';

    function _getData() {

        return self.get();
    }

    this.getDataOther = function() {
        return _getData();
    }

    this.getData = function() {
        return _data;   //Changed this line to just return data
                        //Before, it did the same thing as _getData()
    }   

    //this.init(_data); //Commented out this function (it was changing the base_class' data)
}

new_class.prototype = base_class.prototype;

var instance = new new_class();

alert(instance.getData());
alert(instance.getDataOther());
```

Your english is fine by the way :)

Comment: thanks, this works now =) ... but why is getData() now "null" and not the "test" from the extending class ???

Comment: Uncomment `this.init(_data)`. I commented it out so that I could make sure it was seeing the parent's variable.